# Analytic functions on entire $\mathbb C$.

Tags: complex-analysis

When speaking of analytic functions, I always read the analytic function on a Domain included in $\mathbb C$ or a disk. I ask myself: are there analytic functions on entire $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Exponential function, polynomials, and a few others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Such a function is called "entire." See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function).